# My code won't compile, why?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I've a code and I guess I made everything right. Can anyone tell me why it's not working?
Even it says `error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier` and many errors (total 102) like  that. I've declared them like a=0.

What's wrong with it?

PS: explanatory sentences are written in my local language don't mind them at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>//kutuphane ekleniyor
#include <windows.h>//kutuphane ekleniyor

struct OGRENCI {//ogrenci struct yapisi tanimlaniyor
    char isim[15];//struct yapisi degiskenleri
    int vize;//struct yapisi degiskenleri
    int final;//struct yapisi degiskenleri
    char bolum[15];//struct yapisi degiskenleri
}kisi[10],yedek[10],silinecek[10];//struct yapisina kisi ve yedek isimleri veriliyor

void kayit_ekle();//fonksiyonlar tanimlaniyor
void ara_bul();//fonksiyonlar tanimlaniyor
void listele();//fonksiyonlar tanimlaniyor
void bul_degistir();//fonksiyonlar tanimlaniyor
void kayit_sil();//fonksiyonlar tanimlaniyor
char menu();//fonksiyonlar tanimlaniyor
int sayac;//global bir sayac eklendi kisi syisini bulmak icin

main()
{//ana fonksiyon
    char secim;//secim adinda bir degisen tanimlaniyor
    do {
        secim=menu();//menuden gelen tus algilaniyor
        switch(secim)//menuden gelen veriyi karsilastirmaya sokuyor
        {
            case '1': kayit_ekle();break;//menuden gelen veri 1 ise kayit ekleme fonksiyonu cagiriliyor
            case '2': listele();break;//menuden gelen veri 2 ise listeleme fonksiyonu cagiriliyor
            case '3':ara_bul();break;//menuden gelen veri 3 ise arabul fonksiyonu cagiriliyor
            case '4':bul_degistir();break;//menuden gelen veri 4 ise buldegistir fonksiyonu cagiriliyor
            case '5':kayit_sil();break;//menuden gelen veri 5 ise kayit silfonksiyonu cagiriliyor

        }
    } while(secim<='5' && secim>='1');//karsilastirma menuden gelen verilerin 1 ile 5 arasinda ise
}//ana fonksiyon sonu

char menu(){//menu fonksiyonu
    char tus;//tus adinda char tipinde degisken tanimlaniyor
    printf("1-kayit ekle\n2-listele\n3-arabul\n4-buldegistir\n5-sil\n");//manu secenekleri ekrana yazdiriliyor
    tus=getch();//kullanicinin girdigi tus algilaniyor
    return tus;//menu fonksiyonunun cagirildigi yere kullanicinin girdigi tus dönduruluyor
}//menu fonksiyonu sonu

void kayit_ekle(){//kayit ekleme fonksiyonu
    char tus2;//tus2 adinda char tipinde degisken tanimlaniyor
    FILE *dosya;//file tipinde bir dosya adinda bir pointer tanimlaniyor
    dosya=fopen("a.txt","w");//dosya önceki verilerin ustune yazmak icin aciliyor

    do{
        printf("%d.kisi adi giriniz",sayac+1);//kullanicidan isim isteniyor
        scanf("%s",kisi[sayac].isim);//kullanicini girdigi veri struct yapisina aktariliyor
        fflush(stdin);//veri degiskene aktarildiktan sonra gerekli alan bosaltiliyor
        printf("%d.kisinin bölum giriniz",sayac+1);//kullanicidan bölum isteniyor
        scanf("%s",kisi[sayac].bolum);//kullanicini girdigi veri struct yapisina aktariliyor
        fflush(stdin);//veri degiskene aktarildiktan sonra gerekli alan bosaltiliyor
        printf("%d.kisi vizesi giriniz",sayac+1);//kullanicidan vize isteniyor
        scanf("%d",&kisi[sayac].vize);//kullanicini girdigi veri struct yapisina aktariliyor
        fflush(stdin);//veri degiskene aktarildiktan sonra gerekli alan bosaltiliyor
        printf("%d.kisi finali giriniz",sayac+1);//kullanicidan final isteniyor
        scanf("%d",&kisi[sayac].final);//kullanicini girdigi veri struct yapisina aktariliyor
        fflush(stdin);//veri degiskene aktarildiktan sonra gerekli alan bosaltiliyor
        printf("yeni kayit icin e basin ve menuye dönmek icin herhangi bir tusa basin");//veriler girildikten sonra kullanicidan yeni veri girmek istermisiniz diye soruluyor
        tus2=getch();//kullanicinin girdigi karakter tus2 degiskenine aktariliyor

        fprintf(dosya,"%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n",kisi[sayac].isim,kisi[sayac].bolum,kisi[sayac].vize,kisi[sayac].final);//veriler dosyaya yaziliyor
        sayac++;//whileicin sayac 1 arttiriliyor
    }while(tus2=='e' || tus2=='E');//eger kullanici devam etmek isterse tekrar dön
    fclose(dosya);//dosya kapatiliyor
}//kayit ekleme fonksiyonusonu

void listele(){//listele fonksiyonu
    FILE *dosya;//file tipinde bir dosya adinda bir pointer tanimlaniyor
    dosya=fopen("a.txt","r");//dosya önceki verileri okumak icin aciliyor

    int a=0;
    int i;

    while(!feof(dosya)){//dosya sonuna kadar dön
        fscanf(dosya,"%s%s%d%d",yedek[a].isim,yedek[a].bolum,&yedek[a].vize,&yedek[a].final);//veriler dosyadan okunuyor
        a++;      //while icin a arttiriliyor
    }//dosya sonuna kadar dön sonu
    for(i=0;i<(a-1);i++)//yedek yapisinin sonuna kadar dönuluyor
        printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n",i+1,yedek[i].isim,yedek[i].bolum,yedek[i].vize,yedek[i].final);//okunan veriler ekrana yaziliyor
    fclose(dosya);//dosya kapatiliyor
}//listele fonksiyonu sonu

void ara_bul(){//arabul fonksiyonu
    char kelime[150];//kelima adinda char tipinde bir degisken tanimlaniyor
    printf("Aranacak Kelimeyi girin");//kullanicidan aranacak veri isteniyor
    scanf("%s",&kelime);//girilen veri kelime degiskenine aktariliyor
    FILE *dosya;//file tipinde bir dosya adinda bir pointer tanimlaniyor
    dosya=fopen("a.txt","r");//dosya önceki verileri okumak icin aciliyor
    int a=0,i;//degiskenler tanimlaniyor dönguler icin
    while(!feof(dosya)){//dosya sonuna kadar dön
        fscanf(dosya,"%s%s%d%d",yedek[a].isim,yedek[a].bolum,&yedek[a].vize,&yedek[a].final);//dosyadan veriler okunup yedek yapisina aktariliyor
        a++;     //while icin a 1 arttiriliyor
    }//dosya sonuna kadar dön sonu
    for(i=0;i<(a-1);i++){//yedek yapisinin sonuna kadar dönuluyor
        if(strcmp(kelime,yedek[i].isim)==0)
        {//eger aranan kelime yedek yapisinin ismine esit ise asagidakileri yap
            printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n",i+1,yedek[i].isim,yedek[i].bolum,yedek[i].vize,yedek[i].final);//veriler ekrana yadiriliyor
        }//eger aranan kelime yedek yapisinin ismine esit ise asagidakileri yap sonu
    }//yedek yapisinin sonuna kadar dönuluyorsonu
    fclose(dosya);//dosya kapatiliyor
}//arabul fonksiyonu sonu

void bul_degistir(){//bul degisrtir fonksiyonu
    char kelime[150];
    printf("Degisecek Kisiyi girin");//degisecek kisi kulanicidan aliniyor
    scanf("%s",&kelime);//kullanicinin girdigi veri kelime degiskenine ataniyor
    FILE *dosya;//file tipinde bir dosya pointeri tanimlaniyor
    dosya=fopen("a.txt","r");//a.txt dosyasi sadece okunmak icin yaziliyor
    int a=0,i;//kullanilacak degiskenler tanimlaniyor
    while(!feof(dosya)){//dosya sonuna kadar dönuluyor baslangic
        fscanf(dosya,"%s%s%d%d",yedek[a].isim,yedek[a].bolum,&yedek[a].vize,&yedek[a].final);//dosyadan alinan veriler yedek yapisina aktariliyor
        a++;     //yedek degiskenini her seferinde farkli gelmesi icin a her seferinde arttiriliyor
    }//dosya sonuna kadar dönuluyor sonu
    for(i=0;i<(a-1);i++){//yedek yapisina alinan verilerin isleme sokulmasi
        if(strcmp(kelime,yedek[i].isim)==0)//eger degisecek kelime yedek yapisinin ismine esit ise asagidakileri yap
        {
            printf("%dninci kisinin adini giriniz",i+1);//kullanicidan yeni isim isteniyor
            scanf("%s",yedek[i].isim);//isim yedek yapisinin degisecek kismina ataniyor
            fflush(stdin);//degiskene aktarildiktan sonra o kisim bosaltiliyor
            printf("%dninci kisinin bölumunu giriniz",i+1);//kullanicidan yeni bölum isteniyor
            scanf("%s",yedek[i].bolum);//bölum yedek yapisinin degisecek kismina ataniyor
            fflush(stdin);//degiskene aktarildiktan sonra o kisim bosaltiliyor
            printf("%dninci kisinin vizesini giriniz",i+1);//kullanicidan yeni vize isteniyor
            scanf("%d",&yedek[i].vize); //vize yedek yapisinin degisecek kismina ataniyor
            fflush(stdin);//degiskene aktarildiktan sonra o kisim bosaltiliyor
            printf("%dninci kisinin Finalini giriniz",i+1);//kullanicidan yeni final isteniyor
            scanf("%d",&yedek[i].final);//final yedek yapisinin degisecek kismina ataniyor
            fflush(stdin);//degiskene aktarildiktan sonra o kisim bosaltiliyor

        }
    }//yedek yapisina alinan verilerin isleme sokulmasi sonu
    fclose(dosya);//dosya sadece okunmak icin acilan dosya kapatiliyor

    //simdi bu kisimda degistirilen yedek yapisini a.txtnin uzerine yazarak bul degistir örnegimizi bitirecegiz
    FILE *dosya2;//file tipinde bir dosya2 pointeri tanimlaniyor
    dosya2=fopen("a.txt","w");//a.txt dosyasi önceki veriler silinecek sekilde aciliyor
    int i2;//integer tipinde for döngusu icin i2 degiskeni olusturuluyor
    for(i2=0;i2<(a-1);i2++){//yine yedek degiskeninin sonuna kadar dönuluyor
        fprintf(dosya2,"%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n",yedek[i2].isim,yedek[i2].bolum,yedek[i2].vize,yedek[i2].final);
    }//yedek degiskeninin sonuna kadar dönme sonu
    fclose(dosya2);//acilan dosya kapatiliyor
}//bul degistir fonksiyonu sonu

void kayit_sil(){//kayit sil fonksiyonu
    char kelime[150];
    printf("Silinecek Kisiyi girin");//silinecek kisi kulanicidan aliniyor
    scanf("%s",&kelime);//kullanicinin girdigi veri kelime degiskenine ataniyor
    FILE *dosya;//file tipinde bir dosya pointeri tanimlaniyor
    dosya=fopen("a.txt","r");//a.txt dosyasi sadece okunmak icin yaziliyor
    int a=0,i=0,kacinci;//kullanilacak degiskenler tanimlaniyor
    while(!feof(dosya)){//dosya sonuna kadar dönuluyor baslangic
        fscanf(dosya,"%s%s%d%d",yedek[a].isim,yedek[a].bolum,&yedek[a].vize,&yedek[a].final);//dosyadan alinan veriler yedek yapisina aktariliyor
        a++;     //yedek degiskenini her seferinde farkli gelmesi icin a her seferinde arttiriliyor
    }//dosya sonuna kadar dönuluyor sonu

    for(i=0;i<(a-1);i++){//yedek yapisina alinan verilerin isleme sokulmasi
        if(strcmp(kelime,yedek[i].isim)==0)//eger silinmesi gereken kisi adi yedek yapisinin ismine esit ise asagidakileri yap
        {            kacinci=i;//aranan verinin kacinci oldugu bulunuyor
        }//eger silinmesi gereken kisi adi yedek yapisinin ismine esit ise asagidakileri yapsonu

    }//yedek yapisina alinan verilerin isleme sokulmasi sonu
    for(i=0;i<(kacinci);i++){//verinin bulundugu yere kadar dön
        strcpy(silinecek[i].isim,yedek[i].isim);
        //kacinciya kadar olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
        strcpy(silinecek[i].bolum,yedek[i].bolum);
        //kacinciya kadar olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
        silinecek[i].vize=yedek[i].vize;
        //kacinciya kadar olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
        silinecek[i].final=yedek[i].final;
        //kacinciya kadar olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
    }
    //verinin bulundugu yere kadar dön sonu
    for(i=(kacinci+1);i<=(a-1);i++){//silinen veriden sonrakini silinecek kismina ata
        strcpy(silinecek[i-1].isim,yedek[i].isim);//kacincidan sonra olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
        strcpy(silinecek[i-1].bolum,yedek[i].bolum);//kacincidan sonra  olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
        silinecek[i-1].vize=yedek[i].vize;//kacincidan sonra  olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
        silinecek[i-1].final=yedek[i].final;//kacincidan sonra  olan kisimlar silinen yapisina aktariliyor
    }//silinen veriden sonrakini silinecek kismina ata sonu


    fclose(dosya);//dosya sadece okunmak icin acilan dosya kapatiliyor

    //simdi bu kisimda degistirilen yedek yapisini a.txtnin uzerine yazarak bul degistir örnegimizi bitirecegiz
    FILE *dosya2;//file tipinde bir dosya2 pointeri tanimlaniyor
    dosya2=fopen("a.txt","w");//a.txt dosyasi önceki veriler silinecek sekilde aciliyor
    int i2;//integer tipinde for döngusu icin i2 degiskeni olusturuluyor
    for(i2=0;i2<(a-1);i2++){//yine silinecek degiskeninin sonuna kadar dönuluyor
        fprintf(dosya2,"%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n",silinecek[i2].isim,silinecek[i2].bolum,silinecek[i2].vize,silinecek[i2].final);
    }//silinecek degiskeninin sonuna kadar dönme sonu
    fclose(dosya2);//acilan dosya kapatiliyor

}//kayitsil fonksiyonu sonu
```

Comment: please format your code...

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice.

Comment: this question would be marked off-topic , post your question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sasha: Code Review is only for working code.

Comment: @someonetesting: You should not only create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also tell us in which line the first error occurs. When debugging, always start with the first error. Many other errors are often subsequent errors.

Comment: @honk `(74) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'`

is the first occurrence and 101 more follows this.

Comment: @someonetesting: Thank you, but please always put the error message directly into the question (you have to use the _edit_ button below your question for doing that afterwards). Please also repeat the line that causes the error so that it easy to find in your code. No reader wants to count up to 74.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a compiler (likely a version of MSVC older than from VS 2013) that doesn't allow declarations mixed with statements in C mode.

Either compiler your program with MSVC from VS 2013 or later, use GCC with `-std=gnu99` or make sure your declarations are always at the start of a block.  Another alternative might be to compile the program as C++ (just change the extension to `.cpp`).